# Return value from SQL database for Sagepay using PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, database, opayo

The website I'm working on is sending the incorrect Billing Country information to Sagepay (this field is now mandetory on 3.00 update) and I'm trying to find a way to pass the correct information within the PHP file.

The current line to send this information is:

```
$crypt .= "&BillingCountry=".$orderArray["country"];
```

The problem with this is that the "country" field in the orderArray gives the country name as set in our CMS, not the ISO code that Sagepay requires.

The correct ISO codes are held within an SQL database so the information is available. The database table holds unique ID, name, ISO code, ISO number plus some other site-relavent information.

I need to replace the above crypt with this:

```
$crypt .="&BillingCountry=".$countryISO;
```

Where the $countryISO is added into the code as a query. This query should look in the ISO Code column (isocode) of the Countries database table and return the ISO code value in correspondance with the "country" name in the orderArray.

I've tried to put something together myself following php used in other files for the site which appear to be acheiving something similar. for example:

```
$countryISO = $dbA->query("SELECT isocode FROM $tableCountries WHERE name=".$orderArray["country"]);
```

I've also tried:

```
$countryISO = $dbA->retrieveAllRecordsFromQuery("SELECT isocode FROM $tableCountries WHERE name=".$orderArray["country"]);
```

There is a php file included on the site server that has the 'query' and 'retrieveAllRecordsFromQuery' functions, among others (e.g count, fetch, retrieveAllRecords) and also includes a funciton relating to $dbA which I believe connects to the database.

I need some advice as to how I can achieve pulling the ISO Code from the SQL database. Is my code anywhere near what I need?

Comment: How specifically is this code failing?  Other than not properly using prepared statements, what happens when you execute the query?  I *suspect* you're not wrapping a string value in quotes (a problem which becomes moot when using prepared statements).

Comment: you should wrap name value with quotes:  `WHERE name='".$orderArray["country"]."'"`

Comment: David, I'm not familiar with PHP (completely out of my depth really) but have been tasked with sorting this. The only way I know this is failing is by uploading this to our live server and using Sagepay's test function. I'm just receiving an error for 'Billing Country value is invalid' when submitting the information to Sagepay which means it's not giving the correct value (ISO code e.g GB). I don't have any way of seeing _what_ value it is actually getting, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution by using similar code used for another gateway for the website. This has solved the Billing Country issue and is now sending data successfully to Sagepay on the 3.00 protocol.

Solution:

```
    $countryMatch = $orderArray["country"];
    $cResult = $dbA->query("select * from $tableCountries where name=\"$countryMatch\"");
    if (count($cResult) > 0) {
        $cRecord = $dbA->fetch($cResult);
        $customerCountry = $cRecord["isocode"];
    } else {
        $customerCountry = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, in sql statements, when you want to filter a string field, you should wrap the field value with `single quote : '` or `double quote: "`.

second, the code:

```
 $countryISO = $dbA->query("SELECT isocode FROM $tableCountries WHERE name=".$orderArray["country"]);
```

will not save the `iso code` in `$countryISO`. to do that you must use `fetch_row` in `mysqli`:

```
 $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT isocode FROM $tableCountries WHERE name='".$orderArray["country"]."'");
 $row=$result->fetch_row();
 $countryISO =$row[0];
```

Now you can change your previous code to:

```
 $crypt .= " BillingCountry='".$countryISO."'";
```

P.S. As you did not mention, I assumed that $dbA is a `mysqli` object. if it is not, there is a similar procedure for `PDO` objects with small changes.

To create $mysqli object used in the above:

```
 $mysqli=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Ormoz, I gave this a go but I think I'm missing something! I got this error when testing: _Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in FILENAME.php on line 106_  Line 106 is the $row=$result code. Do I need to call the database using $mysqli as I've seen in some other documentation?

Comment: @Lauren It appears that the `mysqli` object ($dbA) is not constructed. I edited the answer and included the line to create a `mysqli` object. this time I renamed `$dbA` to `$mysqli`.

Comment: you should add this line in the beginning of the code

Comment: I'm still getting a variety of errors even when using the $mysqli code you added. I believe the $dbA is mysql (not mysqli) - would this make a difference to using fetch_row? The $dbA is used in other select queries on other php files so maybe I need to reference this correctly at the beginning of the document so it's constructed? I have a db access file in php which is where the $dbA reference comes from. What would you suggest to try next?

Comment: @Lauren please see where `$dbA` is defined. you will find out the class name there.

Comment: Would this be where $dba is defined? `$dbA = new dbAccess();`  I'm afraid I'm really new to php, sorry! @Ormoz

Comment: @Lauren then you should look up for the `dbAccess` class definition . see it extends which class.